# error: no match for 'operator='

Tags: ros, std-msgs, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I get this error when building the package:

```
/home/ken/cws/src/mathematics/src/evenNumberGenerator.cpp:24: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'mathematics::TwoData_<std::allocator<void> >::_data2_type {aka std_msgs::Int8_<std::allocator<void> >}' and 'int')
             number.data2 = i*2;
                          ^
```

Basically, I am working on [this issue](http://answers.ros.org/question/266493/can-a-node-listen-to-two-other-nodes/), finally I think I figured it out the correct way of using custom messages in my package but I guess I made some mistake in my code.

msg file:

```
ken@ken-Satellite-L500D:~$ cat cws/src/mathematics/msg/TwoData.msg
std_msgs/Int8 data1
std_msgs/Int8 data2
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266666/error:-no-match-for-%27operator=%27/) by [Kenn](https://answers.ros.org/users/31209/kenn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try with

```
number.data2.data = i*2;
```

?

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2017-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kenn](https://answers.ros.org/users/31209/kenn/) on 2017-07-18**:
Thank you, that was it! But why? I don't remember such a syntax was mentioned anywhere in tutorials.

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2017-07-18**:
I think it is because std_msgs/Int8 is a structured data (a class I think). If you try with just Int8 you can get direct access to the data. Check [this](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Int8.html).

**Comment by [Kenn](https://answers.ros.org/users/31209/kenn/) on 2017-07-18**:
I just attempted compiling the package with Int8 data1 (data2), without std_msgs/ in my msg folder, it gives some dependency errors. I believe in some of the answers here I saw the correct use of message declaration was like this "package/type name".

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-18**:
Note: the primitive is `int8`, the message name is `Int8` (with a capital `i`). The first is a built-in, the second is a message in `std_msgs`. The latter *requires* you add the `std_msgs/` prefix.